# python3 function correctness

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I have a function below:

```
def f(s1,s2):
         s=''
         for i in range(min(len(s1),len(s2))):
            s = s1[i] + s2[i]
         if len(s1) < len(s2): return s + s2[len(s1):]   
         else: return s + s1[len(s2):]
print(f('1234','abc'))
```

this function should print the two strings together as 1a2b3c4, but I'm only getting the last half 3c4 when I run it. Any ideas as to why this is happening? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also looks like you are re assigning the variable 's' whereas you should be concatenating.

Replace : 
s = s1[i] + s2[i]

With:
s = s + s1[i] + s2[i]

Answer (score 4):

Because you're doing it the hard way.

```
s = ''.join((x + y) for (x, y) in zip(s1, s2))
```

Comment: oh. but what does zip mean?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: now tell him how to click the link.

Comment: oh that looks pretty easy. Thanks! is that what join does too?

Comment: @GregS haha don't worry that I can do.

Answer (score 1):

You meant `s +=` inside the `for` loop, right?

Comment: is that what it should be?

Comment: @Romulus It works, then. Then you concatenate all pairs, instead of taking last one.